# ка переключать цвет на выбраный спан и сохранить значение выбраного спана в переменную javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```css
.product-details .product-sizes {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.product-size.selected:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.product-size.selected {
    border: 1px solid #fa6f57;
    background: #fa6f57;
    color: #fff;
}
.product-size:hover {
    border: 1px solid #fa6f57;
    color: #fa6f57;
}
.product-size {
    color: #1f1f1f;
    border: 1px solid #1f1f1f;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding: 0 4px;
    min-width: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="product-sizes">

<span class="product-size selected" data-product-size="s">S</span>
<span class="product-size" data-product-size="m">M</span>
<span class="product-size" data-product-size="l">L</span>

<select id="ProductSize" name="size" size="1" style="display: none;">
<option value="<script>let val = "s"</script>">S</option>
<option value="<script>let val = "m"</script>">M</option>
<option value="<script>let val = "l"</script>">L</option>
</select>
</div>
</body>
```

```
<div class="product-sizes"><span class="product-size selected" data-product-size="s">S</span><span class="product-size" data-product-size="m">M</span><span class="product-size" data-product-size="l">L</span><select id="ProductSize" name="size" size="1" style="display: none;"><option value="s">S</option><option value="m">M</option><option value="l">L</option></select></div>
```

Comment: Создайте воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 0):

Если отталкиваться от данного примера, то предполагаю, что при выборе SPAN должен выбираться соответствующий select

```
// Создаём глобальную переменную для сохранения в неё нашего значения, _согласно_ВОПРОСА_!
var GlobalSize;


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

// Щелчок по элементам
// Вешаем клик на родителя, чтобы не вешать обработчик на кадлый элемент отдельно
    document.querySelector('.product-sizes').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    // теперь проверяем, что кликнули именно по необходимому элементу (проверяем по классу), другие будут игнорироваться

        if(e.target.classList.contains('product-size')){

            // запускаем необходимые действия
            // Удаляем староый seelect (через цикл для надёжности)
            document.querySelectorAll('.product-size.selected').forEach( function(element) {
                element.classList.remove('selected');
            });
            // Теперь выбираем текущий элемент
            e.target.classList.add('selected');
            // Сохраняем в переменную согласно вопроса
            GlobalSize = e.target.dataset.productSize;
            // Меняем селект, ведь это надо, это подсказывает мой хрустальный шар требуется?
            document.querySelector('#ProductSize').value = e.target.dataset.productSize;
        }
    })

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/0z72a91u/

Comment: а в зависимости от выбора размера в select может подставлятся цвет на спан?

Comment: Зачем вам это, если у вас по-умолчанию селект скрыт? Я для наглядности убрал сокрытие.

Comment: яб добавил фото рядом с выбором и хорошо получилось бы выбирали бы удобный вариант

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/0z72a91u/1/
там одно лишнее действо с .toLowerCase(), там оказывает в одном ригистре, но лишним не будет, я думаю. Но, думаю, можно и убрать
https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/0z72a91u/2/
И забыл про непонятно зачем нужную запись в глобальную https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/0z72a91u/3/

Comment: Благодарю это оно)

Comment: еще маленький ньюанс можно цвет такой же как у тега спан в селект подставить у выбранного размера?

Comment: <script>
let mass= [s,l,x,xl,xxl];

for(){
 
}
</script>

<div class="product-sizes">
 <span class="product-size selected" data-product-size="s">S</span>
 <span class="product-size" data-product-size="m">M</span>
 <span class="product-size" data-product-size="l">L</span>
 
 <select id="ProductSize" name="size" size="1">
  <option value="s">S</option>
  <option value="m">M</option>
  <option value="l">L</option>
 </select>
</div>

Comment: в цикле это нужно вывести с размерами с массива и выбором селектед у наименьшего размера

Comment: Мой мозг отказывает дальше понимать что вы хотите, а хрустальный шар, только недавно купленный, перегорел от ваших хотелок, придётся относить по гарантии в ремонт. Выражайтесь конкретнее и подробнее.

Comment: у меня есть массив с размерами let mass = [s,l,xl,xxl]; он отличается для каждого товара, как мне его с помощью js вывести и спан и в селект тоесть сформировать циклом for вывев тот код который Вы делали и установить выделение по умолчанию у нулевого элемента массива а в селекте выделеный размер выделить тем же цветом что и в выделеном спане. Тот же код только html часть вывести в цикле беря в даные из массива и закрасить select, так как тег спан красится а select белый остается некрасиво  получается https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/0z72a91u/3/

Comment: А почему такое не сделать на стороне сервера. Я так понимаю это на PHP и магазин какой-то? HTML код же генерируете, вот там этот массив и разбирайте. Смысла нет дублировать работу на клиенте.

Что касается "красить селект" - то надо понять откуда и какие цвета брать. Я пока нигде не вижу цвета в коде.

Comment: http://korzinka.byethost9.com/ вот сайт нужно нажать на товар и там справа нужно вывести размеры под ценой пример как это выглядит сдесь https://garne.com.ua/p97075 я базу данных неиспользую вместо нее таблица гугл там размеры буду брать

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что HTML код из первого сообщения не существует сейчас на сайте и не генерируется на данный момент?

Comment: да пока не генерируется потом интегрирую

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BaNru/0z72a91u/4/

Comment: Ура интергрировал заработало с гугл таблицы берет данные и при оплате показывает размер спасибо вам за помощь  http://korzinka.byethost9.com/   вот результат нажмите на одежду и также на определенную карту товара и там загружаются размеры додумал уже сам)))